# Checking whether an element is in a C++ set is really slow

Tags: c++, performance, set

I'm implementing an algorithm that implies a lot of checking whether elements are in a set/list. I was using `std::vector` containers but time was increasing exponentially as the vector would grow.

I've decided I would try using `std::set` containers in order not to have to explore the entire container to know whether it contains a certain element.
I implemented the following function that checks whether an element is part of a given set:

```
bool in_set(set<Node> node_set){
  return node_set.find(*this) != node_set.end();
}
```

However, that function is taking around 2s for very small sets (1-3 elements) which makes my entire algorithm unusable.

The custom class I'm using look like this:

```
class Node{
    public:
      int d;
      int h_score;
      int coordinates [3];
      Node* parent_address;
};
```

The comparison operator that I implemented look like this:

```
bool operator<(Node other) const{
  return concatenate(concatenate(this->coordinates[0], this->coordinates[1]), this->coordinates[2]) < 
  concatenate(concatenate(other.coordinates[0], other.coordinates[1]), other.coordinates[2]);
}
```

Edit: The concatenate function does not seem to take a lot of time while executing, it looks like this:

```
int concatenate(int i, int j) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int x = i; x <= j; x++) {
       result = result * 10 + x;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Do you know why it is taking so much time, and more importantly, how to make it faster?

Comment: Do you really pass the set like that? By value? You are also missing semi-colons on class declarations, please post actual real compilable code. Read about how one creates a [mcve].

Comment: s/exponentially/linearly/ maybe?

Comment: Also, definitely post the source of `concatenate`.

Comment: if you have a problem of performance it is in your operator< so in concatenate

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I'm new to c, should I pass a pointer instead?

Comment: in `in_set` and your operator< use const reference as parameter, to not copy the set each time

Comment: What's your actual data? It shouldn't take seconds to pass a small `set` by value. Your `concatenate` will take a long time if `i` is small and `j` is large, and it may also overflow and cause undefined behaviour. This needs a [mcve].

Comment: What is `concatenate` supposed to do?

Comment: 2 seconds to execute `in_set` on a set of 1-3 elements is extreme even with all the inefficiencies in your code. I suspect something else is going on.

Comment: Concatenate is creating an unique int identifier for every Node to make them easily comparable

Comment: @Codophage you don't need to create a unique identifier to compare two nodes, compare them directly as may be my answer

Comment: This is [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). `Y` here is how to fix your badly used `set` where in fact problem `X` is performance issue of some data structure. I'm not convinced that `set` is proper solution for `X`, I suspect that some sort of B-tree would be a better choice.

Comment: @MarekR the set seems the good solution because he says he searches a lot if a node is in its sequence

Comment: @Codophage I edited my proposal of operator<, my previous was wrong

Comment: @bruno how do you know? Do you know the `X` issue? I'm suspecting some collision detection problem in 3 dimensions since his `Node` has `int coordinates [3]`, so simple `set` is still a bad choice.

Comment: @MarekR I edited my answer to explain why it works

Comment: @bruno again: how do you know that? You are not `OP`. Maybe you know him in person or problem he actually stunning with.

Comment: @MarekR I don't know him but he says *I'm implementing an algorithm that implies a lot of checking whether elements are in a set/list* then *Do you know why it is taking so much time, and more importantly, how to make it faster?* I just answer to him, no ?

Comment: I’m implementing the a star algorithm for 3D path finding

Comment: @Codophage is my proposal ok for you ?

Comment: The copy was causing the main speed issue, I’ll make sure I’ll test your fix for the concatenation as well as Botje’s to see if can make me gain some milliseconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can try to pass Set as const & and not in operator< also as const &.

```
bool in_set(const set<Node>& node_set){
  return node_set.find(*this) != node_set.end();
}
```

And

```
bool operator<(const Node& other) const
```

It will use ref instead of a copy of your set and Node objects.

Comment: the real problem is not the copy, but the way the operator< works using the very expensive concatenate

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know why it is taking so much time

`concatenate(1, 100000000)` takes 1.3 second on my raspberry pi, that way to do is too slow, and in fact useless

Note also that because of the possible overflows *concatenate* can give the same result for different nodes, this is non compatible for an *operator<*

> how to make it faster?

you have to find something else than these calls of concatenate to implement your *operator<*

What is your need ? is the order in the set is important or it can be replaced by any one else ?

It is not mandatory to create a unique identifier to compare two nodes, compare them directly, for instance :

```
bool operator<(const Node & other) const{
  if (coordinates[0] < other.coordinates[0]) 
    return true;
  if (coordinates[0] >= other.coordinates[0]) 
    return false;

  if (coordinates[1] < other.coordinates[1])
    return true;
  if (coordinates[1] >= other.coordinates[1])
    return false;

  return (coordinates[2] < other.coordinates[2]);
}
```

To understand that *operator<* works you can consider *node.coordinates* supports a big number having 3 times the size of an *int*, so I compare the higher bits, then if equals the medium bits, then if equals the lower bitsused for a *set*

Comment: Just use `std::tie` or `std::make_tuple` here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `operator<` takes a **copy** of the Node. There's also no need to create strings to compare, the built-in `tuple` class can do that:

How about:

```
bool operator<(const Node& other) const {
    return std::make_tuple(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]) < 
           std::make_tuple(other.coordinates[0], other.coordinates[1], other.coordinates[2]);
}
```

Comment: there is exactly the problem for `in_set`